# How to detect if an interface{} is a pointer?

Tags: pointers, go

I'm wondering how can you know if the interface is of type pointer.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type str struct {
    a, b string
}

func main() {
    var s str
    x := &s
    t := reflect.TypeOf(interface{}(x))
    fmt.Printf("%v", t.Size())
}
```

Comment: there are you interfaces in your code.

Comment: I've corrected the question

Answer (score 6):

Use a type switch if you already know the type(s):

```
switch v.(type) {
case *str:
    return "*str"
case str:
    return "str"
}
```

If you don't, then you can use `if reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind() == reflect.Ptr {}`

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/8-leSJRhXT)